# Shell returns all files when regex doesn't match any file in directory?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sh, solaris

I use below command in shell file and works fine in the directories that regex matches.
Problem is, it lists all files when there is no match for regex. Anyone knows why it has this behaviour?
Are there anyway to avoid it?

```
find  . -type f -mtime +365 | egrep '.*xxx.yyy*.*'|grep -v "[^.]/" | xargs ls -lrt | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-9
```

thanks for your time.
Note: I m using this script with splunk forwarder on solaris 8.

Comment: Whole thing can be written in `find` itself. Can you clarify what are you trying with this `find` command?

Comment: I tried using all in find command before. for some reason it didn't work. Script is about file aging for specific format-extensions of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input of `xargs` is empty, then it will execute `ls -lrt` in the current folder.

Try `xargs -i "{}" ls -lrt "{}"` instead. That forces `xargs` to put the input arguments into a certain place in the command that it executes. If it doesn't have any input, it can't and will skip running the command at all.

If you have GNU `xargs`, you can use the switch `--no-run-if-empty` instead.

If that doesn't work, try to move all the `grep`ing into `find`, so you can use `-ls` to display the list of files. That will also avoid running the `ls` command if no file matches.

Comment: I'm waiting for an `--xml` or `--csv` option for `ls` to fix all those parsing issues :-) If you have GNU, you can at least use `ls --format="..."` to control the output.

Comment: -i "{}" worked out for my problem. thanks for your help. I finished a script 2 months back in Ubuntu. For some reason, probably SAs disabled some commands in the solaris server, that didn't work. thanks a lot again

Comment: Solaris has often only the "pure" Posix-style commands which are often very limited in what they can do. My solution was to compile all the basic GNU stuff starting with BASH and [Coreutils](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Coreutils)